# Change ListTile Widget at Runtime Problem

Tags: flutter

https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar

I created a calendar using the package i linked. Trying to update ListTile's leading image at runtime.
im trying to send data as string so every event has to have a spectacular string. i have to Data class to send variables to next page and it's working but image variable always stays null. Hope that someone can explain why  setState function below is not working .Thanks.

```
    class Calender extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CalenderState createState() => _CalenderState();
}

class Data {
  String title, image, subText, subTitle;

  Data({this.image, this.title, this.subTitle, this.subText});
}

class _CalenderState extends State<Calender> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Map<DateTime, List> _events;
  List _selectedEvents, names;
  String image = " ";
  AnimationController _animationController;
  CalendarController _calendarController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("work");
    super.initState();
    final _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
    _calendarController = CalendarController();
    _events = {
      _selectedDay: [
        'TRY 1',
      ],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 15)): ['TRY 2'],
      _selectedDay.add(Duration(days: 20)): ['TTRY 3'],
    };

    _selectedEvents = _events[_selectedDay] ?? [];
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onDaySelected');
    setState(() {
      _selectedEvents = events;

      //working
    });
  }

  void _onVisibleDaysChanged(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged');
  }

  void _onCalendarCreated(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onCalendarCreated');
  }

  Data _data;

  Data get data {
    if (_data == null) {
      _data = Data();
    }
    return _data;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    names = _events.values.toList();
    //trying to  match strings with elements of list  here but not working
    setState(() {
      if (names[0] == 'TRY 1') {
        //image =
        image = 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/lights.jpg';
        //  'https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/5/18869335/85b9f0bc435132ec116846fafc335030.jpg';
        _data.subTitle = "8.01 PM door opening";
      }
      if (names[1] == 'TRY 2') {
        image =
            'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg';
        _data.subTitle = "8.02 PM door opening";
      }
      if (names[2] == 'TRY 3') {
        image =
            'https://previews.123rf.com/images/alexis84/alexis841404/alexis84140400557/27773925-planet-earth-and-blue-human-eye-elements-of-this-image-furnished-by-nasa-.jpg';
        _data.subTitle = "8.01 PM door opening";
      }
    });

    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(),
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
              children: [
                _buildTableCalendar(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: _buildEventList(image, data),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
 }

  Widget _buildTableCalendar() {
    return TableCalendar(
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        selectedColor: Colors.deepOrange[400],
        todayColor: Colors.deepOrange[200],
        markersColor: Colors.brown[700],
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        formatButtonTextStyle:
            TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.deepOrange[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        ),
      ),
      onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
      onCalendarCreated: _onCalendarCreated,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventList(String image, Data data) {
    print(data.image);
    return ListView(
      children: _selectedEvents
          .map((event) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 0.8),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  subtitle: Text("8 pm"),
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    //image comes here null
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(image),
                  ),
                  title: Text(event.toString()),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      if (event.toString() == "Beyond Akaretler") {
                        print("check1");
                        setState(() {
                          data.image =
                              "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/5/18869335/85b9f0bc435132ec116846fafc335030.jpg";
                          data.title = "TRY1";
                        });
                      }
                      if (event.toString() == "Dorock XL") {
                        setState(() {
                          data.image =
                              "https://www.habervesaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/dorock-xl.jpg-1547825520-810x456.jpeg";
                          data.title = "TRY2 ";
                        });
                      }
                      if (event.toString() == "The Wall Kadıköy") {
                        setState(() {
                          data.image =
                              "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/2/19165732/302d1418f06c81dca13e7c06bcc44ba9.jpg?fit=around|750:500&crop=750:500;*,*";
                          data.title = event.toString();
                        });
                      }
                      Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => EventPage(
                                    data: data,
                                  )));
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}

class EventPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Data data;

  const EventPage({Key key, this.data}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage("${data.image}"), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text("${data.title}"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using setState wrongly. can you upload full widget class state full widget and its private state class

Comment: Please add full code for proper understanding of error

Comment: i've added full code and i know im using it wrong really couldn't figured out how to use it correctly